# Incorrect conversion of image coordinates to viewport coordinates - openseadragon svgOverlay

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I'm trying to load points(image coordinates) from a file and display it on openseadragon using svg-overlay. Converted the points to viewport coordinates using imageToViewportCoordinates but they don't look positioned correctly.
I am using a slider to display different images into the viewer and for each image some points are displayed. The points are correctly marked for some of the images. I just create a single overlay at the beginning, clear elements and set points corresponding to the image in slider change event.

Is it possible that using a single overlay is causing the issue? Do I have to set any offset or make additional tranformations to the svg elements.

[Markers from Matlab plot and Openseadragon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9rKr.jpg).

Comment: Is there a single image in the viewer, or multiple? If there are multiple, you need to be using the imageToViewportCoordinates from the TiledImage, not the one from the Viewport.

Answer (score 0):

> set points corresponding to the image in slider change event

Perhaps waiting until the Viewer open event will work better, as the image dimension properties will be set before using the conversion functions

Comment: Here is how I set the data:
$.ajax({
        url: "/images/<%=@image.id%>/get_slice?slice="+ref_slice_num.toString()
    }).done(function(data){
        viewer.open('/'+data.dzi_url);
    });
setResults(ref_slice_num);

Did you mean to create overlay after viewer open event?

Comment: @db20 Yes, I meant in a handler for, or after, the viewer open event. My reasoning is when you open a new image it's asynchronous, so if you start calling methods that rely on image data they might not be accurate until that data is available